# Set all the columns of a mysql table to a particular value

Tags: mysql, sql

hIs there any way to update all the columns of a mysql table for a particular record in one go to a particular value.

For e.g. I have a table that has around 70 columns , and they are by default set to 0 at the time of creating the table,when I add a new record via PHPmyadmin by just filling in one or two values and submitting it  all the other fields are set to 0 , but I want to set all the fields to 1
many times ,so I need to set all the columns to 1 individually via PHPmyadmin

To speed-en up the process and 
I tried

`UPDATE tablename SET * = '1' WHERE id = '2'` , but it does not work.

If anyone can provide a solution on similar lines , it would be great.

EDIT:

---

Is there a way without specifying all the 70 columns in the SQL statement? that what I am looking for. I do know how to update normally specifying columns in the SQL statement. Thank you.

Comment: If it allowed you to specify all the columns, you would end up updating the id column to 1 as well! Wouldn't you be better changing the default on the columns to be 1.

Comment: You mean all 70 columns are of the same data type? That sounds rather untypical.

Comment: you can consider the id column as the 71th column for convenience sake. Yes all the columns have same data type except the id column. All the column have datatype SMALLINT , and all the columns other than the id column have values 1 or 0 only. It a permission, ACL table.

Comment: So for every permission type you add a new column? If you were to change the format to store each permission in its own row then this mass update would be easier. In fact I would only store granted permissions so the absence of a row means the permission is not granted.

Comment: John you are right, but is there an option to update all the columns , I don't mind if the id gets changed, I can change it manually later. Its lot less work to update a single column.

Comment: Hello Martin, you are right its an ACL table which sets the permissions of various user types, such as Super admin, admin ,data entry user, financial user,  etc where reach row correspond to an user group. Well for the permission I am doing exactly, by default they are set to 0 which means the section is not accessible. If a section is accessible to user, then the column value is 1,  Just for info.

Comment: Well as above I would change the structure so when a new user is added that has no permissions you simply don't insert into the permissions table. If you do want to grant all permissions to user `1234` you could simply do a `SELECT 1234,permission_type_id FROM permission_types` to generate the rows to insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to name each column in an update statement.

Comment: hi, thanks, yep I know I can update the table by specifying the desired columns

Comment: means you MUST specify the desired columns, there is no such thing as UPDATE mytable SET DEFAULT VALUES WHERE ID = 12

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a way to update all 70 columns to a single value with a short, simple statement, then I recommend that you write a stored procedure to do the update. That way you only need to write out the full update syntax once, and can re-use it over and over by calling the stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE update_all_columns (p_new_value SMALLINT, p_id INT) ...

CALL update_all_columns(1,2);
```

Another trick is to use the information_schema.columns table to generate the update statement, making it less tedious to code the stored procedure.

Something like this:

```
SELECT concat('UPDATE ',
table_name,
' SET ',
group_concat(column_name separator ' = p_new_value, '),
' = p_new_value',
' WHERE id = p_id;') as sql_stmt
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_schema = 'your_schema' 
AND table_name = 'tablename'
AND column_name != 'id'
```