# Mysql Update all table columns from n/a to NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, loops

I have a table in my database and some fields are n/a not NULL because i imported them from a text file.I want a query that loops every column of my table if the column has a value of n/a update it to NULL.Any solution?

Comment: I would probably start with this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245425/set-all-the-columns-of-a-mysql-table-to-a-particular-value?rq=1 If you have trouble, I'll try and knock something up. Unfortunately, I don't have MySQL as my main database here, so it might be difficult

Answer (score 1):

Use the find and replace functionality of a text editor to replace all the N/A values with Null before importing. Not sure what you'll have to use to represent Null in your text file but there should be something that MySQL will understand.

Comment: if i have text in the text file example abn/an => abNULLn ?

Comment: If your value delimiter is comma then you can do ,n/a, => ,NULL,

Comment: still not the answer i'm looking for but i'm considering your question

Comment: I'm not sure this would work. If you're importing a CSV, importing `NULL` as a value might well just import it as a string: `'NULL'`

Comment: @Darkzaelus "Not sure what you'll have to use to represent Null in your text file but there should be something that MySQL will understand."

Comment: Apologies, I don't seem to be very good at reading this morning!